# Bootstrap carousel image out of frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm having trouble with Bootstrap carousel. I have rounded edges on my carousel but when the image slides, the corner of image appears. I can't explain with words.

[image]

Here is a normal and correct carousel image with rounded edges.

[image]

But when image slides to another image, it goes out of the frame and makes a solid edge.
Is there a way to fix this using Bootstrap 3?

Thankyou, Ričards.

Comment: Can you show us what actually happens? (With a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example)

Comment: Here is a code example but it doesn't work on jsfiddle. No rounded edges too.

https://jsfiddle.net/LL4rj5k8/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "solid edges" you see are the semi-transparent "controls".  I have exaggerated them to make the effect more apparent.  You will likely want to adjust their styling to something more to your liking.  I would recommend removing the gradient background and using a text shadow in stead to help the control stand out.

```css
.carousel {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.carousel .item img {
  border-radius: 64px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..."></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..."></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..."></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```